# We have to show that $n\times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$ are nilpotent.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n\times n$ matrices with entries from some field $\mathbb{F}$. Let $c_1,\ldots,c_{n+1}$ be $n+1$ distinct elements in $\mathbb{F}$ such that $A+c_1B,\ldots,A+c_{n+1}B$ are all nilpotent. Then how can I show that $A$ and $B$ are nilpotent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the polynomials in $\Bbb F[x]$ of degree $\leq n$, $p_{ij}(x)=\big((A+xB)^n\big)_{ij}$. Notice that each of them has $c_1,\dots,c_{n+1}$ as roots. Deduce that $A^n=0$ and that $B^n=0$ (for the latter consider the coefficients at $x^n$).

Comment: It is clear that $A$ is nilpotent but $B$ is nilpotent, is not clear. Can you give some more details?

Comment: the hint for $B$ is to use that the coefficients of the polynomials at $x^n$ (just as all the coefficients) are zero, but they are simply the entries of $B^n$